# Mockoon how to add filter to CRUD route

Tags: query-string, crud, mockoon

New to Mockoon. I have a data bucket like this:

```
[
    {
      "id": 1,
      "parentObjectServiceType": 14,
      "parentObjectId": 4,
      "title": "Note Title Public",
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "parentObjectServiceType": -1,
      "parentObjectId": -1,
      "title": "Note Title Private",
    }
]
```

It is connected to a CRUD route (called notes) so that I can do GET, PUT, POST, and DELETE calls automatically. In addition to this, I would like to filter out the GET using query strings such as:

/notes?parentObjectServiceType=14&parentObjectId=4

This should return the first element of the array above.

I am unable to do this. Any pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[Update 2024-01-01]

It is now possible to [filter on CRUD routes](https://mockoon.com/docs/latest/api-endpoints/crud-routes/#filtering-sorting-and-pagination-on-the-main-get-route) using query parameters and operators.

You can achieve what you want by doing something like this:

`/notes?parentObjectServiceType_eq=14&parentObjectId_eq=4`

---

This is not yet possible with CRUD routes. There is an [opened issue](https://github.com/mockoon/mockoon/issues/1047) that is on the roadmap though.

The alternative is to use a combination of templating helpers on a regular HTTP route, like you can see [here](https://github.com/mockoon/mockoon/discussions/1053#discussioncomment-7663592):

```
{{{ stringify (oneOf (
    filter
      (dataRaw 'notes')
      (object type=(queryParamRaw 'parentObjectServiceType') )
  ))
}}}
```

But it's not ideal and you loose the rest of the CRUD features.

Comment: This gives an empty result. I tried:
{{{ stringify (oneOf (
        filter
          (dataRaw "notes")
          (object parentObjectServiceType=(queryParam 'parentObjectServiceType'))
      ))
    }}}
also I tried without oneOf and it gives empty array.

Comment: You mentioned losing the CRUD feature, if I put another HTTP GET /notes above the CRUD, then shouldn't it intercept only GET verb while all other verbs like PUT, POST etc. will be dealt with CRUD?

Comment: Yes, you are right, a GET route above should only intercept the GET method and the rest of the CRUD route should work.  Even I sometimes forget about my own app's features! 

Concerning the empty result, I am not sure what is wrong, but I noticed in your bucket content that you have trailing commas after the last properties. This is not valid JSON and the bucket will not be generated. It will be considered as a string.
One thing I want to improve in the future is to inform the user that the generated data bucket is not a valid JSON.

Comment: I removed the comma from the end and tested again, which did not solve the problem. Funny thing is that it works just fine with the UrlParam. It also works if I hardcode the value e.g. (object parentObjectServiceType=14)

Comment: I kindof made it work by putting a fake arithmetic function around it like: (object parentObjectServiceType=(round (queryParam 'parentObjectServiceType'))). There got to be a better way of doing this. This feature becomes important as many REST queries use query strings for search functions.

Comment: This has probably to do with the fact that queryParams are always string values. Compared a to number it seems to not be working. We will look into it to improve this in the future. There is also a parseInt helper that you can use.

Comment: I've updated my answer after v6.1.0 release which added query params filtering.